# Recursive template explanation C++

Tags: c++, templates, recursion, variadic-templates, template-specialization

```
template<typename... ArgTypes>
int add(ArgTypes... args);

template<typename T, typename... ArgTypes>
int add(T t, ArgTypes... args)
{
    int sum = 0;
    return t + add(args...);
}
template<> int add() {
    return 0;
}
```

How to add more operations like multiplication and subtraction? What does `template<> int add()` mean?

Could anyone explain in detail how this recursive template works?

UPD: Thank you guys regarding subtraction, yes, subtraction is not commutative so it's not really suitable for such recursive templating.

UPD2: Added a call stack as a reference for community
[image: Call Stack for variadic templates]

Comment: `template<>` is for [template specialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization).

Comment: To get rid of "recursion": `template<typename... ArgTypes>
int add(ArgTypes... args) { return (0 + ... + args); }` (C++17).

Comment: @Jarod42  thanks, can I keep the recursion and just add the other operations?  Maybe using class templates?

Comment: Note that these functions do yield lots of (maybe) unwanted conversions if invoked as `add(1.1, 2.2, 3.3);` - the result will be 6, as the specialization forces implicit conversions of all following operands.

Comment: Also note that if your goal is obfuscation, all you're doing is making your code harder to read for yourself, not harder to understand for a machine. Unless you release your code without optimizations, the compiler will just eliminate all these recursive calls and replace it with some simple instructions.

Comment: yes, we turn on optimizations

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is quite common recursive [variadic template](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack). The idea is that we use recursion

`f(x0, x1, ..., xn) = f(f(x0, x1, ..., xn-1), xn) (1)`,

in your sample

`add(x0, x1, ..., xn) = add(x0, x1, ..., xn-1) + xn`.

Variadic templates provides simple and useful way to create such a structure.

First, define the general signature of the template (without implementation, becouse we never use general form)

```
template<typename... ArgTypes>
int add(ArgTypes... args);
```

Now specialize template fuction for case with at least one parameter. We use recursion which extract first argument and calls itself recursively with reduced by one the number of parameters.

```
template<typename T, typename... ArgTypes>
int add(T t, ArgTypes... args)
{
    int sum = 0;
    return t + add(args...); // recursive call without first arg
}
```

To stop recursion, we use template specialization for empty template parameters list (we add `0` at the last step).

```
template<> int add() {
    return 0;
}
```

For multiplication you need just change `+` by `*`, becuse general recursive form (1) is identical in both case, and change `return 0` to `return 1` (multiply by `1` at the last step).

In the substraction case the general form of the recursion (1) is unusable, because `a-b != b-a`, ambiguity arises. Also with division and other noncommutative operations. You will have to clarify operations order.

Comment: Yes, regarding a - b != b - a  the absence of commutativeness is not an issue. That's just for obfuscation. Thanks.

Comment: Just a small nit-pick: the fact that subtraction is not _commutative_ isn't really a problem: `subtract(a,b)` is unambiguously different from `subtract(b,a)`. Ambiguity arises because the operation isn't _associative_: does `subtract(a,b,c)` mean `a-(b-c)` or `(a-b)-c`?

Answer (score 10):

Here's my attempt at an explanation.

Firstly:

```
template<typename... ArgTypes>
int add(ArgTypes... args);
```

This is the starting point. It says "there exists a function called `add` that takes **zero or more** generic arguments". It doesn't contain an implementation, so on its own it amounts to a kind of promise to the compiler that such a function will exist.

Then we have:

```
template<typename T, typename... ArgTypes>
int add(T t, ArgTypes... args)
{
    int sum = 0; // This line isn't doing anything!
    return t + add(args...);
}
```

This says "here is a function called `add` that takes **one or more** generic arguments". It includes an implementation. Part of that implemantation recursively calls `add(args...)` with all arguments but the first (i.e. zero or more). We've been told this exists by the first declaration above.

If there is at least one argument in `args`, then this recursive call will end up calling the the exact same function again. But what happens when `args` contains zero arguments? We need a version (specialization) of the function to handle that case, which is the only case not handled by our second definition. That's where the third declaration comes in:

```
template<> int add() {
    return 0;
}
```

This defines a function called `add` that takes **zero** arguemnts.

So, in summary:

1. The second declaration defines a function taking **one or more** arguemnts
2. The third declaration defines a function taking **zero** arguments
3. Together, this means we have a function taking **zero or more** arguments,
   as declared by the first declaration.

Answer (score 3):

> Could anyone explain in detail how this recursive template does work?

I can try.

First you have

```
template<typename... ArgTypes>
int add(ArgTypes... args);
```

It's a variadic template function declaration: you declare that exist an `add()` function that receive a variadic (zero or more) number of argumens.

Attention: you declare but not define the function.

Second: you declare **and** **define**

```
template<typename T, typename... ArgTypes>
int add(T t, ArgTypes... args)
{
    int sum = 0;
    return t + add(args...);
}
```

a **different** template function `add()` that receive a template type argument (`t`) and a variadic template list of arguments (`args...`).

The line

```
int sum = 0;
```

is completely un-useful because declare an unused variable but the following line

```
return t + add(args...);
```

do the work returning the sum between `t` and the sum (`add(args...)`) between the following `args...`.

So with `add(args...)` is recursively called `int add(T t, ArgTypes... args)` when `args...` (because it's a better match) isn't empty and `int add(ArgTypes... args)` when `args...` is a empty list.

But remember that `int add(ArgTypes... args)` is declared but not defined.

The last point is

```
template<> int add() {
    return 0;
}
```

that is the definition of a **full specialization** (remember that you can't partial specialize a template function but you can full specialize it) of the first template function in case of empty list.

Off Topic suggestion: you don't need the first template function; you can substitute it with a simpler not-template function.

You can rewrite the code as follows

```
int add()
 { return 0; } 

template <typename T, typename... ArgTypes>
int add(T t, ArgTypes... args)
 { return t + add(args...); }
```

and as suggested by Jarod42, if you can use C++17, you can completely avoid recursion using template-folding

```
template <typename... ArgTypes>
int add (ArgTypes... args)
 { return (... + args); }
```

or maybe using `auto` for returning type.

> How to add more operations like multiplication and subtraction?

No idea about subtraction (how is defined a variadic subtraction?) but, for multiplication you can use something similar (but the ground case must return `1`, not `0`)

```
int mult ()
 { return 1; } 

template <typename T, typename... ArgTypes>
int mult (T t, ArgTypes... args)
 { return t * mult(args...); }
```

or using template folding, from C++17,

```
template <typename... ArgTypes>
int mult (ArgTypes... args)
 { return (... * args); }
```

Comment: Good explanation, but note that `(... */+ args)` does not compile for empty `...`, unlike OP's code.

Answer (score 0):

Recursion has a [base case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion#base_case). So you can think of `template<> int add()` as the template specialization covering the base case when `T` is an integer. This will be called when `sizeof...(args)` is zero. See [Demo Here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/9LFeMZgKVgsEVKw6).

For multiplication you can do this:

```
template<typename T, typename... ArgTypes>
int mult(T t, ArgTypes... args)
{
    return t * mult(args...);
}
template<> int mult() {
    return 1;
}
```

I'm not sure what you intend to do for subtraction though. We can have the sum (addition) of numbers and the product (multiplication) of numbers, but there is nothing like ??? (subtraction) of numbers.